# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/client/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, heroku, http-status-code-404

https://github.com/sw9142/thankshare

for the last a few days, I have been struggling to solve out this error, but i couldn't..

checking at the heroku logs, it says that '/client/build/index.html' can not be found.

```
2021-07-02T04:46:14.791646+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/client/build/index.html'
```

and this is error appeared in the development tool with another error(is this the reason causing 404 error??)

```
Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self' data:". 


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)createError.js:16 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at e.exports (createError.js:16)
at e.exports (settle.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.p.onreadystatechange (xhr.js:62)
```

so this is how i have been trying to solve this out adding the following to server.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") { 
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client/build")));  
        app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        const fullPath = path.join(__dirname,  '../client', 
                                  'build', 'index.html')
         res.sendFile(fullPath)
   })
 }
```

Any one who knows what i did wrong, please let me know!!!